# Change Wordpress default registration error text [Error: This username is invalid because it uses illegal characters. Please enter a valid username.]

Tags: php, wp-login-form

May I know how could I change the error text? Example, I want change it from.

[Error: This username is invalid because it uses illegal characters. Please enter a valid username.]

to

[Error: Username invalid. Please enter a valid username.]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this via '[registration_errors](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/registration_errors/)' filter hook. The hook filters the WP_Error object that holds all the current errors. The code used will be something like this:

```
add_filter( 'registration_errors', function( $errors ){
    if( $errors->get_error_messages( 'invalid_username' ) ) {
        $errors->remove('invalid_username');
        $errors->add('invalid_username', '<strong>Error</strong>: My custom error message');
    }
    return $errors;
});
```

**Please note** that we checked the presence of the target error message by its code "invalid_username", but this code may contain a different message for the username if it is found in the array of 'illegal_user_logins' which may contain a list of disallowed usernames, so if you need a different message for the disallowed username error you may use the second parameter "$sanitized_user_login" to check if it's in the disallowed list and change the error message if so. Your code may be something like this:

```
add_filter( 'registration_errors', function( $errors, $sanitized_user_login ){
    
    if( $errors->get_error_messages( 'invalid_username' ) ) {
        
        // Get the list of disallowed usernames
        $illegal_user_logins = array_map('strtolower', (array) apply_filters( 'illegal_user_logins', array() ));
        
        // Set our default message
        $message = '<strong>Error</strong>: My custom error message';
        
        // Change the message if the current username is one of the disallowed usernames
        if( in_array( strtolower( $sanitized_user_login ), $illegal_user_logins, true) ) {
            $message = '<strong>Error</strong>: My custom error message 2';
        }
        
        $errors->remove('invalid_username');
        $errors->add('invalid_username', $message);
    }
    
    return $errors;
}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me! It works well! I want to change text for successful registration. 
[Registration complete. Please check your email, then visit the login page.]
May I know is there any documentary for reference? I am new to WordPress and appreciate for your help.

Comment: You can do this the same way, but using 'wp_login_errors' filter instead. You can find an example of how to do this on the [documentation page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_login_errors/#comment-5069) of this filter.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot change it, as it is hard-coded and unfiltered in core.

See https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/user.php#L185